# Distinct "RestoreDirectory"s do not work

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

`RestoreDirectory` is set to two `OpenFileDialog()`s but they behave as if one `OpenFileDialog()`. I mean, when I use one of them and exit, then use other one, it shows the directory of the first one.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd_1;
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd_2;
}

public MainWindow()
{
    ofd_1 = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd_2 = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
}

private fnc_1 ()
{
    ofd_1.RestoreDirectory = true;
}

private fnc_2 ()
{
    ofd_2.RestoreDirectory = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RestoreDirectory` is not implemented on [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx), so it doesn't actually do anything. You can use the [`InitialDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) property to set the directory yourself though.